# nuxt link takes two clicks to correct path

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt / Vue and in my site header router links. The problem I am seeing is when I click the router link to a path:

```html
<nuxt-link to="/product-innovation/type">
  <span class="link-brdr">Product</span>
</nuxt-link>
```

the route changes to the path : /product-innovation and not /product-innovation/type

if I click the nuxt link a second time it then will navigate to the correct page route.

Comment: What do you see in your vue devtools `routing` tab? Also, did you tried giving a `name` to your component and using `:to="{ name: 'name-of-the-component' }"`?

Comment: Hey @kissu! thanks for the tip about dev tools. When I click the nuxt link the vue dev tools routing tab shows TWO paths. First the correct path I am trying to get to and then it shows the main route path.

Comment: You do have a middleware or a router guard? Some auth? Why is the second one even reached?

Comment: @kissu found the issue! previous dev had a strange method that was forcing a router push with a variable that did not include if the nuxt link had numerous paths. Thank you for the input as always! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, the issue was about a previous developer who had some strange way of using `router.push`.

OP was able to solve it by himself thanks to some tips (mainly vue devtools, routing tab)!